# Complex number, finding complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

I have to find the complex plane region that is determined by the following condition:

$$|2z+3|\gt 4$$

I develop using my definition of $z$ as $a+bi$

and I get to

$$a^2+3a-b^2 \gt \frac{7}{4}$$

After this, I do not know what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $\cdots+b^2>\cdots$?

Answer (score 3):

$$|2z+3|^2 = |2a+3+2bi|^2=(2a+3)^2+4b^2>16$$
Dividing both sides by $4$, we get
$$\left(a+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+b^2>4$$

The resulting region is the exterior of a circle, not including the boundary.

(You made a mistake with the minus in front of $b^2$ )

Comment: what did you do with the $b^2$?

Comment: @DemianJimenez I corrected my answer.

Comment: shouldn't it be $-4b^2$ since the $i^2$ goes as a $-1$?

Comment: @DemianJimenez No, the moduĺus of a complex number is $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}

Comment: I see my mistake, thanks

Comment: @DemianJimenez If I answered your question, you can mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Such problems are problems on the geometry of complex numbers.

Let's first use, not the complex variable $z$, but the complex variable
$$
w = 2z + 3.
$$
In the $w$-plane, your inequality is
$$
|w| > 4,
$$
which is simply the strict exterior of the disc with center $0$ and radius $4$.

What does going back to the $z$ variable do to that disc?
$$
z = {1 \over 2}\left(w - 3\right),
$$
so: (i) shift the disc by 3 units "to the left" along the real axis, and then (ii) downscale the entire plane by factor $1/2$.  We end up with a disc centered at $z = -3/2$ and with radius $2$.  The exterior of that disc is the desired region.

A good source: Part 2 of [Lectures and Problems: A Gift to Young Mathematicians](https://books.google.com/books/about/Lectures_and_Problems_A_Gift_to_Young_Ma.html?id=b-gUCwAAQBAJ).

Answer (score 0):

You can just write as $|z+3/2|>2$, i.e. $|z-(-3/2)|>2$, so the region is given by the points whose distance to $-3/2$ is  bigger than $2$, i.e. the region is the  plane after removing the closed disc of center $-3/2$ and radius $2$.